# Python String Split Order Wrong

Tags: python

My current code

```
defname,last_name):
    if not isinstance(reg, int) or \
       not isinstance(year, int) or \
       not isinstance(degree, str) or \
       not isinstance(other_name, str) or \
       not isinstance(last_name, str) :
       print("Invalid string argument")
    elif 0<=year<=4:
        l.append((reg,year,degree,other_name,last_name))
    else: print("Invalid year")

def p
    reg,year,degree,other_name,last_name = student.strip().split(" ",4)
    reg=int(reg)
    year=int(year)
    fullName=last_name+ ", " + other_name
    thisYear="Year " + str(year)
    print(format(fullName, "<32s")+format(reg,"<7d")+format(degree,">6s"),format(thisYear,">6s"))
```

how can I do this effectively with the right formats? I am trying to make it so it uses both functions and is checking for valid

Comment: I think the second argument to `split` should be 5.

Comment: @AurelBílý if i do that and then run the program, it returns :  `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)`

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the reason it's printing on that side, that's because of the way you called `.split()`. Calling it with the 4 will of course restrict it to splitting 4 times. And since it splits from left to right, once it has made its 4th split (ie. after 'Homer'), it will simply return the rest of the string as a whole (ie. 'J Simpson').

If I were you, I would do it like this:

```
reg,year,degree,*name = student.strip().split(" ")
name = list(reversed(name))
fullname = name[0] + ', ' + ' '.join(name[1:])
```

Doing `*name` lets you grab multiple tokens as a list, and then process them however you like.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but why cant I use the split as 5?

Comment: You can if you want, that will just making it more rigid. Calling split without a number will split on every single space in the text, no matter how many there are, and using `*name` will ensure that this doesn't cause any `ValueError`s.

Comment: If i enter 5 as the split, it prints the first 2 but then says `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)`

Comment: That's because you're trying to shove 6 values into 5 slots. Doing `*name` gets around that by scooping up all of the remaining values at the end into one list.

Comment: So there's no way unless i have another argument?

Comment: Yes. You can't shove a variable number of objects into a fixed number of slots. You can fix the number of objects by specifying the number of times to split, as you did, but you didn't like the result, so you're going to to have to do something more complicated. Have you tried my solution? Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Your solution is perfect, just wanted to know if there were any other ways. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First off, wouldn't you want it to print `Simpson, Homer J`?

Secondly, it prints it `J Simpson, Homer` because this is what your list looks like:`[1342347, 2, G401, Homer, J Simpson]`. 
It splits it this way because you told it to split at each space it sees, and to make a maximum of 4 separate strings. It doesn't know that middle names belong to `other_name`, so you have to do a little more work in your string parsing to get that to behave as desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are limiting the number of splits to 4.

Thus, for the third line, the 4th space that gets split is between "Homer" and "J". Thus, "J" and "Homer" are in the same string after the split.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm